# Move cursor/focus on other textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've added toolbar to the textfield and also on textfield it can show keyboard or show UIPickerView like on image

[image]

How to move cursor/focus from on textfield to other textField programmatically(Next, and Back buttons on Toolbar)?

P.S. I know how to call the method(set selector when adding UIBarButtonItem to Tool). I just need the code for moving the focus/cursor

Comment: if you have text fields a,b,and c, to produce the keyboard or if keyboard already visible, focus the cursor on another textfield, just call a.becomeFirstResponder() or whatever text field you want to be focused on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move focus to another responder you can use`[textField2 becomeFirstResponder];`. I can also suggest a [IQKeyboardManager library](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) which adds a similar toolbar automatically.

Comment: Я пометил твой ответ как правильный, так как эта библиотека - это то что надо, она даже решает проблему когда клавиатура появляется а текстовое поле уплывает выше экрана и его бывает не видно когда есть scrollview

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`UIResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html) methods [`-resignFirstResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder) & [`-becomeFirstResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder) on the respective `UITextField` objects to lose and gain focus respectively.

**For example:**

```
[nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```